when i connect phantom wallet in website on Mobile phone is redirect To phantom Mobile app browser
When I connect Phantom Wallet on a mobile phone through a website, it redirects to the Phantom Mobile app browser. However, we prefer users to only go to the app for connecting and signing messages, and then redirect back to the mobile Chrome browser for other wallet methods. How to redirect back to browser ? Please Help

You can use deeplinks:
https://phantom.app/learn/blog/the-complete-guide-to-phantom-deeplinks
Deep Link will open Phantom Application and redirect to your web app with encrypted data that you can decrypt to get the wallet address and a session that can be used later for further processes
